# Get a YAML file with HTTP and use it as a variable in an Ansible playbook

Tags: http, ansible, yaml

### Background

I have a YAML file like this on a web server. I am trying to read it and make user accounts in the file with an Ansible playbook.

```yaml
users:
  - number: 20210001
    name: Aoki Alice
    id: alice
  - number: 20210002
    name: Bob Bryant
    id: bob
  - number: 20210003
    name: Charlie Cox
    id: charlie
```

### What I tried

To confirm how to read a downloaded YAML file dynamically with `include_vars`, I had written a playbook like this:

```yaml
- name: Add users from list
  hosts: workstation
  tasks:
    - name: Download yaml
      get_url:
        url: http://fqdn.of.webserver/path/to/yaml.yml
        dest: "/tmp/tmp.yml"
      notify:
        - Read yaml
        - List usernames

  handlers:
    - name: Read yaml
      include_vars:
        file: /tmp/tmp.yml
        name: userlist

    - name: List usernames
      debug:
        var: "{{ item }}"
      loop: "{{ userlist.users }}"
```

### Problem

In the handler `Read yaml`, I got the following error message. On the target machine (`workstation.example.com`), `/tmp/tmp.yml` is downloaded correctly.

```
RUNNING HANDLER [Read yaml] *****
fatal: [workstation.example.com]: FAILED! => {"ansible facts": {"userlist": []},
"ansible included var files": [], "changed": false, "message": "Could not find o
r access '/tmp/tmp. yml' on the Ansible Controller.\nIf you are using a module a
nd expect the file to exist on the remote, see the remote src option"}
```

### Question

How can I get a YAML file with HTTP and use it as a variable with `include_vars`?

Comment: Well, it's suggesting an option to try; you need to be clear what happens on which host (Ansible controller vs target). Another way would be to use the `uri` module to get the contents in a variable, then `set_fact` and the `from_yaml` filter to extract it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another option would be to use the `uri` module to retrieve the value into an Ansible variable, then the `from_yaml` filter to parse it.

Something like:

```
- name: Add users from list
  hosts: workstation
  tasks:
    - name: Download YAML userlist
      uri:
        url: http://fqdn.of.webserver/path/to/yaml.yml
        return_content: yes
      register: downloaded_yaml
    - name: Decode YAML userlist
      set_fact:
        userlist: "{{ downloaded_yaml.content | from_yaml }}"
```

Note that `uri` works on the Ansible Controller, while `get_url` works on the target host (or on the host specified in `delegate_to`); depending on your network configuration, you may need to use different proxy settings or firewall rules to permit the download.

Comment: I want to mark this answer as "most helpful", because this solution doesn't have to use `delegate_to:` or `connection: local`, and doesn't store the `users.yml` on the control host (you don't have to delete it with additional tasks). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `include_vars` task looks for files on the local (control) host, but you've downloaded the file to `/tmp/tmp.yml` on the remote host. There are a number of ways of getting this to work.

Perhaps the easiest is just running the download task on the control machine instead (note the use of `delegate_to`):

```
  tasks:
    - name: Download yaml
      delegate_to: localhost
      get_url:
        url: http://fqdn.of.webserver/path/to/yaml.yml
        dest: "/tmp/tmp.yml"
      notify:
        - Read yaml
        - List usernames
```

This will download the file to `/tmp/tmp.yml` on the local system, where it will be available to `include_vars`.  For example, if I run this playbook (which grabs YAML content from an example gist I just created)...

```
- hosts: target
  gather_facts: false
  tasks:
    - name: Download yaml
      delegate_to: localhost
      get_url:
        url: https://gist.githubusercontent.com/larsks/70d8ac27399cb51fde150902482acf2e/raw/676a1d17bcfc01b1a947f7f87e807125df5910c1/example.yaml
        dest: "/tmp/tmp.yml"
      notify:
        - Read yaml
        - List usernames

  handlers:
    - name: Read yaml
      include_vars:
        file: /tmp/tmp.yml
        name: userlist

    - name: List usernames
      debug:
        var: item
      loop: "{{ userlist.users }}"
```

...it produces the following output:

```
RUNNING HANDLER [Read yaml] ******************************************************************
ok: [target]

RUNNING HANDLER [List usernames] *************************************************************
ok: [target] => (item=bob) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "bob"
}
ok: [target] => (item=alice) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "alice"
}
ok: [target] => (item=mallory) => {
    "ansible_loop_var": "item",
    "item": "mallory"
}
```

---

Side note: based on what I see in your playbook, I'm not sure you want
to be using `notify` and handlers here. If you run your playbook a
second time, nothing will happen because the file `/tmp/tmp.yml`
already exists, so the handlers won't get called.

Answer (score 1):

With @Larsks 's answer, I made this playbook that works correctly in my environment:

```yaml
- name: Download users list
  hosts: 127.0.0.1
  connection: local
  become: no
  tasks:
  - name: Download yaml
    get_url:
      url: http://fqdn.of.webserver/path/to/yaml/users.yml
      dest: ./users.yml

- name: Add users from list
  hosts: workstation
  tasks:
  - name: Read yaml
    include_vars:
      file: users.yml
  - name: List usernames
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.id }}"
    loop: "{{ users }}"
```

### Point

##### Run `get_url` on the control host

As @Larsks said, you have to run the `get_url` module on the control host rather than the target host.

##### Add `become: no` to the task run on the control host

Without "become: no", you will get the following error message:

```
TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"ansible_facts": {}, "changed": false, "msg":
 "The following modules failed to execute: setup\n setup: MODULE FAILURE\nSee
 stdout/stderr for the exact error\n"}
```

##### Use `connection: local` rather than `local_action`

If you use `local_action` rather than `connection: local` like this:

```yaml
- name: test get_url
  hosts: workstation
  tasks:
  - name: Download yaml
    local_action:
      module: get_url
      url: http://fqdn.of.webserver/path/to/yaml/users.yml
      dest: ./users.yml
  - name: Read yaml
    include_vars:
      file: users.yml
  - name: output remote yaml
    debug:
      msg: "{{ item.id }}"
    loop: "{{ users }}"
```

You will get the following error message:

```
TASK [Download yaml] ********************************************************
fatal: [workstation.example.com]: FAILED! => {"changed": false, "module_stde
rr": "sudo: a password is required\n", "module_stdout":"", "msg":"MODULE FAIL
URE\nSee stdout/stderr for the exact error", "rc": 1}
```

##### `get_url` stores a file on the control host

In this situation, the `get_url` module stores `users.yml` on the control host (in the current directory). So you have to delete the `users.yml` if you don't want to leave it.